# .htaccess rewriting certain word in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I cannot seem to find the answer to this

I am looking for a .htaccess rewrite way to turn this url

http://www.mydomain.com/Virtuemart.html?keyword=adobe&page=shop.browse

to

http://www.mydomain.com/virtuemart.html?keyword=adobe&page=shop.browse

So basically i just want to change the capital V

There are many pages and variables after the ? so doing it one by one is almost impossible

is their an easy way to do this.

Many thanks for your time

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite (under apache), you can stick something like this in the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Virtuemart.html /virtuemart.html [L,QSA]
```

The query string just gets appended to the end untouched. If you want to redirect the browser, add a **R=301** flag to the end (or just **R** if you don't want 301). This makes it so when someone goes to http://www.mydomain.com/Virtuemart.html, they'd actually get served the page at `/virtuemart.html`.

Comment: Thanks for that, added the following to the .htaccess file but when i click on a Virtuemart.html?= link in google it still goes to an error page, so not rewritting to the new virtuemart RewriteRule ^Virtuemart.html /virtuemart.html [L,QSA,R=301]